# ruby on rails new method failed not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

below is my code, but my problem is in my _form.html.erb, when i use the form_for method for one of my method update, it works, but when i want to create a new data, it failed.

home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @inputs = Person.all
  end

  def new
    @input = Person.new
  end

  def create
    @input = Person.new(input_params)
    respond_to do |x|
    if @input.save
        x.html {redirect_to :action => 'index'}
    else
        x.html {render :action => 'new'}
    end
   end
  end

  def show
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |x|
      if @input.update(input_params)
        x.html {redirect_to :action => 'index'}
      else
        x.html {render :edit}
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @input = Person.find(params[:id])
    @input.destroy
    respond_to do |x|
      x.html {redirect_to :action => 'index', notice: 'data was delete successfully'}
    end
  end

  private

  def input_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :weight, :height, :color, :age)
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @input, url: {:action => "update"} do |person| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :name %><br>
    <%= person.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :weight %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :weight %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :height %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :height %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :color %><br>
    <%= person.text_field :color %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= person.label :age %><br>
    <%= person.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= person.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources:home
root 'home#index'
```

index.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Listing</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th> Weight</th>
            <th> Height</th>
            <th> Color</th>
            <th> Age</th>
            <th colspan="4"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @inputs.each do |person| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= person.name %></td>
            <td><%= person.weight %></td>
            <td><%= person.height %></td>
            <td><%= person.color %></td>
            <td><%= person.age %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show',home_path(person.id) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_home_path(person.id) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', home_path(person.id), method: :delete, data: {action: 'are you sure?'} %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
     </tbody>
 </table>
 <br>
 <%= link_to 'New Test', new_home_path %>
```

and lastly a screenshot of what the error is:

[image: this is happening when i click on 'New Test']

It has no problem when i click on 'Edit' and the 'Update'

New update, after removing url{action: 'update'}
this problem comes up
[image]

[image: having resources: home and resources:people altogether]

Comment: On your screenshot, you are calling `update` action not `show`. Can you show your `show.html.erb` as well?

Comment: sorry, it is new&create method failed not show

Comment: @ThugForever try removing `url: {:action => "update"}` Rails is smart enough to know if it should do a POST (create) or a PUT (update).

Comment: Are you using `_form.html.erb` for `new`? If you use the same `_form.html.erb` for `new` and `update`, please see my answer below.

Comment: just use = form_for @input do |person| in new form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to `OJ1987`'s answer...

---

Your issue is that [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style) automatically pulls the url from the passed object. In your case, it will expect `people_path`:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
```

... is the equivalent of ...

```
<%= form_for @person, as: :person, url: people_path(@person), method: :patch, html: { class: "edit_person", id: "edit_person_45" } do |f| %>
```

Thus, when you're using the `resources :home` directive, you're going to end up with [configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) problems.

--

The solution is to put your `@person` functionality in a `PeopleController`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :people #-> url.com/people/new

#app/views/people/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
```

You should [read about `resourceful` routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

---

To get this working with some "static" pages (as it seems you're trying to with your `Home` controller):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :people
root "application#index"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def home
     #app/views/application/home.html.erb
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same `_form.html.erb` for `new` and `edit`, you should do this in your `_form.html.erb`:

`<%= form_for @input do |person| %>`

Not:

`<%= form_for @input, url: {:action => "update"} do |person| %>`

You don't need to add `url: {:action => "update"}` because you use RESTful or the `resources` in your `routes.rb`.

On your second screenshot, it seems that you don't have `resources :people`.

Based on your post `routes.rb`:

```
resources:home
root 'home#index'
```

You don't have: `resources :people`. Add the following on your routes:

`resources :people`

On your third screenshot, notice that you dont have an space for `resources :home`

Do this on your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :home
resources :people
root 'home#index'
```

Comment: What does it says when i failed?

Comment: Add `resources :people` on your routes.rb. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Yeah it kind of work for new test but still wrong for update approach

Comment: How do you say that it is wrong for update approach? You are using RESTful. Follow and try the following tutorial found on this link so you could understand http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Comment: I updated my answer for your third screenshot. I don't think you know the basics for  developing Ruby on Rails. Could you start and following all of tutorials from rails? This is it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, but I have one last question, for the resources, I should include for view: home and database:people? I am kind of confused why you add resource:people

Comment: I add `resources :people` because you are using `People` model. `resources` is for RESTful routing. All Model if you add it on your routing, you should write it as plural.